# Parse.com: Searching a TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, parse-platform

Hey together I am using [Parse](http://www.parse.com) SDK for my App - the interface is build in Storyboard...

I am having a table view which get's his data from Parse, now I want to make it searchable.

I found [this post](https://www.parse.com/questions/programmatic-search-capability-using-parse) and followed it but not came to a running result! :/

The search results are load but I having problems to display them...

I get the following errors:

```
... myApp[..] *** Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:5471
... myApp[...] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

I tried a lot around but don't come to a result, here is my code - can anybody help:

Sorry for my bad english! ;)

```cs
#import "FirstLaunchViewController.h"

@interface FirstLaunchViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstLaunchViewController

#pragma mark - UIViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadObjects];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithClassName:@"teams"];
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"teams";
        self.textKey = @"verein";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        // self.keyToDisplay = @"text";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = NO;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        self.loadingViewEnabled = NO;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 50;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // Configure the cell

    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];

    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = color;

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = color;

    cell.backgroundView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbackground_n.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellbackground_down_n.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0]];
    cell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellarrows.png" ]];

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"verein"];
    } else {

        PFUser *obj2 = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"teams"];
        PFObject *searchedUser = [query getObjectWithId:obj2.objectId];
        NSString *content = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"verein"];
        cell.textLabel.text = content;

        NSLog(@"Content: %@", content);

    }

    return cell;

}

-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: self.parseClassName];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"verein"]; //this is based on whatever query you are trying to accomplish
    [query whereKey:@"verein" containsString:searchTerm];

    NSArray *results  = [query findObjects];

    NSLog(@"%@", results);
    NSLog(@"%u", results.count);

    [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterResults:searchString];
    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return self.objects.count;
    } else {
        return self.searchResults.count;
    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `tableView` initially has no reusable cells to dequeue. You need to check whether the cell returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is nil, and create a cell if it is.

```
PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (!cell)
{
  cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
// Configure the cell

...
```

This way, you are guaranteeing that `cell` has a value, so you can avoid returning nil from this method.

To handle `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` correctly, you'll need to first check which tableView triggered the event, and handle it accordingly. Below is an example of how this could work - you'd need to substitute your own detail view controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  }
  else {
    PFUser *user = PFUser *obj2 = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    MyDetailViewController *detailController = [[MyDetailViewController alloc] initWithObject:user];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:datailController animated:YES];
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!
One last question I still have:
How to get the right `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` ?
I tried: 
`[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
PFObject *selectedObject = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` but in the search display controller I getting a wrong result...

Comment: No worries, I've edited my answer to give you an idea of that could be done.